# how to remove anonymous user role from list of profile members

Tags: views, users

I want to remove anonymous role member from the public list of profile users because anonymous roles cannot join so it is confusing to see the anonymous user at top of public profile list.

Comment: How is this list being generated?

Comment: It is being generated through views module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a filter for user: UID and set to "not equal to" and enter 0 for the value.